# What is the logic behind the algorithm

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7

I am trying to solve a problem from codility

> "Even sums"

but am unable to do so. Here is the question below.

Even sums is a game for two players. Players are given a sequence of N positive integers and take turns alternately. In each turn, a player chooses a non-empty slice (a subsequence of consecutive elements) such that the sum of values in this slice is even, then removes the slice and concatenates the remaining parts of the sequence. The first player who is unable to make a legal move loses the game.

You play this game against your opponent and you want to know if you can win, assuming both you and your opponent play optimally. You move first.

Write a function:

`string solution(vector< int>& A);`

that, given a zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers, returns a string of format "X,Y" where X and Y are, respectively, the first and last positions (inclusive) of the slice that you should remove on your first move in order to win, assuming you have a winning strategy. If there is more than one such winning slice, the function should return the one with the smallest value of X. If there is more than one slice with the smallest value of X, the function should return the shortest. If you do not have a winning strategy, the function should return "NO SOLUTION".

For example, given the following array:

> A[0] = 4 A[1] = 5 A[2] = 3 A[3] = 7 A[4] = 2

the function should return "1,2". After removing a slice from positions 1 to 2 (with an even sum of 5 + 3 = 8), the remaining array is [4, 7, 2]. Then the opponent will be able to remove the first element (of even sum 4) or the last element (of even sum 2). Afterwards you can make a move that leaves the array containing just [7], so your opponent will not have a legal move and will lose. One of possible games is shown on the [following picture](https://codility-frontend-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/media/task_img/even_sums_game/media/auto/tikz242689cc8162bed50db48168cf844337.png)

Note that removing slice "2,3" (with an even sum of 3 + 7 = 10) is also a winning move, but slice "1,2" has a smaller value of X.

For the following array:

> A[0] = 2 A[ 1 ] = 5 A[2] = 4

the function should return "NO SOLUTION", since there is no strategy that guarantees you a win.

Assume that:

N is an integer within the range [1..100,000]; each element of array A is an integer within the range [1..1,000,000,000]. Complexity:

expected worst-case time complexity is O(N); expected worst-case space complexity is O(N), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments). Elements of input arrays can be modified.
I have found a solution online in python.

```
def check(start, end):
    if start>end:
        res = 'NO SOLUTION'
    else:
        res = str(start) + ',' + str(end)

    return res

def trans( strr ):
    if strr =='NO SOLUTION':
        return (-1, -1)
    else:
        a, b = strr.split(',')
        return ( int(a), int(b) )


def solution(A):
    # write your code in Python 2.7

    odd_list = [ ind for ind in range(len(A)) if A[ind]%2==1 ] 

    if len(odd_list)%2==0:
        return check(0, len(A)-1)


    odd_list = [-1] + odd_list + [len(A)]
    res_cand = []
    # the numbers at the either end of A are even
    count = odd_list[1]
    second_count = len(A)-1-odd_list[-2]
    first_count = odd_list[2]-odd_list[1]-1
    if second_count >= count:
        res_cand.append(  trans(check( odd_list[1]+1, len(A)-1-count )))

    if first_count >= count:
        res_cand.append(  trans(check( odd_list[1]+count+1, len(A)-1 )))  

    twosum = first_count + second_count
    if second_count < count <= twosum:
        res_cand.append(  trans(check( odd_list[1]+(first_count-(count-second_count))+1, odd_list[-2] )))

    ###########################################
    count = len(A)-1-odd_list[-2]
    first_count = odd_list[1]
    second_count = odd_list[-2]-odd_list[-3]-1
    if first_count >= count:
        res_cand.append(  trans(check( count, odd_list[-2]-1 )))

    if second_count >= count:
        res_cand.append(  trans(check( 0, odd_list[-2]-count-1)) )

    twosum = first_count + second_count
    if second_count < count <= twosum:
        res_cand.append(  trans(check( count-second_count, odd_list[-3])) )



    res_cand = sorted( res_cand, key=lambda x: (-x[0],-x[1]) )

    cur = (-1, -2)
    for item in res_cand:
        if item[0]!=-1:
            cur = item

    return check( cur[0], cur[1] )
```

This code works and I am unable to understand the code and flow of one function to the the other. However I don't understand the logic of the algorithm. How it has approached the problem and solved it. This might be a long task but can anybody please care enough to explain me the algorithm. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `slice` here include the case of the whole sequence?

Comment: yes it does. We can remove the entire sequence in one slice as well.

Comment: I observed that it is all about `the number of odd terms` in the array. If there are `odd` number of `odd terms` in the array, the `second` player wins, otherwise the 'first` player....

Comment: @yobro97 [1, 0] is a counterexample. The first player can remove the zero, and then the second player has no move.

Comment: `non-empty`.....can we take out zero?

Comment: @yobro97 it's not that simple. For instance, in [1,2] first player wins. But in [2,1,2] second player wins. So number of odd numbers is a crucial part. But it's not all that there is to it.

Comment: The evenness of the number of odd numbers and also whether the ends are odd numbers might be enough. That gives 6 different cases I think? even/odd number of odds and 0/1/2 odd ends of the sequence (front/back is irrelevant due to symmetry). I'm not sure if that is enough, but it may be, think about it.

Comment: Is it a twist of nim game?

Comment: @shole well you can think of it that way. But in this case there is only one heap. And you can remove only even number of objects.

Comment: I have found the solution guys if any of you were interested :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I have figured out that the number of odd numbers are crucial to find out the result. Especially the index of the first odd number and the last odd number is needed to calculate the important values.

Now I need to understand the logic behind the comparison such as "if first_count >= count" and if "second_count < count <= twosum".

Update:
Hey guys I found out the solution to my question and finally understood the logic of the algorithm.

The idea lies behind the symmetry of the array. We can never win the game if the array is symmetrical. Here symmetrical is defined as the array where there is only one odd in the middle and equal number of evens on the either side of that one odd.

If there are even number of odds we can directly win the game.

If there are odd number of odds we should always try to make the array symmetrical. That is what the algorithm is trying to do.

Now there are two cases to it. Either the last odd will remain or the first odd will remain. I will be happy to explain more if you guys didn't understand it. Thanks.